# MySQL recommendation, field vs relational table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL INNODB table containing about 2,000,000 rows with 10 fields (table "cars"). It'll keep increasing progressively at a current rate of about 500,000 rows a year. It's a busy table getting different type of queries on average 2-3 times a second 24/7.

The situation right now is that I need to expand the information to include an INT field ("country_id"). But, this field will for at least 99 % of all rows be default "1".

**My question is: Would there be any specific reasons to do either of the following solutions:**

1. Add the INT field to the table and index it ("cars"."country_id")
2. Add a relational table ("car_countries") which includes the fields "car_id" and "country_id"

I setup these examples in the test environment made a few thousand iterations of querying the tables for data to find this out:

1. Database/table size will due to the index increase with 19 % (~21 MB)
2. Queries will take on average 16 % longer (0.37717 secs vs 0.32431 secs for 1,000 queries each)

I've previously tried to keep tables filled with appropriate information for all fields and added relational tables where non-mandatory information was needed for a table but now I've read there's little gain in this as long as there's no need to have arrayed data (which MySQL doesn't handle (and PostgreSQL does)) in the table. In my example a specific car will never be sold to 2 countries so there will never be a need to add more countries to a specific car.

Almost everything is easier with solution 1 and since disk space doesn't really matter. **Should I still consider solution 2 anyway? If so, why?**

Best regards,

/Thomas

Comment: if you really care about size, maybe just add entries to a separate table when country_id != 1. (not recommended)

Comment: A car_countries table would be needed if one car can have more than one country. If no, you can forget about it. As the answer seems to be no, use solution 1.

Comment: @bwoebi Size isn't that important, especially not that kind of size. Your, "not recommended" solution is **solution 2** so I understand you recommend **solution 1** too?

Comment: Your Option 2 is not a bad idea.  I have had to split a table into two for performance, where the 2nd table are fields that are used less often.  So, how often will this field be used?  If a lot, then I would use option 1.  If rarely, go with option 2.  I should clarify, this table would be keyed on the car_id, and not as a both fields. (Change its name to cars_add_fields)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Another vote for **solution 1** then, thanks.

Comment: @AgRizzo Performance matter of course, but what kind of performance? Speed is better with **solution 1** and disk is better with **solution 2** (which neither in this case is a problem really). As said in the post, the new field ("country_id") will not be used more than 1 % of all cases.

Comment: Option #1 is fine, but I'm not sure about the indexing. One general rule for indexing is "high cardinality", which basically means "lots of different, well-distributed values", and with 99% of the `country_id` values set to 1 you don't have high cardinality. If you'll be doing a lot of real-time queries for `country_id != 1` then maybe it's worth it, but if not you may want to leave it out and avoid the overhead of maintaining the index.

Comment: Option 2 should only be implemented when cars can be attached to multiple countries.

Comment: @Thomas - Implement Option 1.  It is easy and requires minimal work.  All I meant to tell you in the previous comment was Option 2 is a reasonable solution, i.e., it is not bad and should not be excluded because it was a bad idea.  If you needed to add an additional 50 fields, then Option 2 (as I described) becomes a better idea.  There are other comments which imply it is a cross-reference table between cars and countries.  I interpret Option 2 as a table of car fields that are rarely used.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thanks, I'll test it out in the dev environment. It takes a while to add an index but when it's there it doesn't really hurt performance, whichever cardinality, except for disk space?

Comment: @AgRizzo I could see this table having maybe 3-4 fields in the future but probably not more than that. If I'd have to put in 50 more fields I'd put them in different relation tables and group them up as much as possible. Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: Thomas: it hurts performance - on paper. Every time you write a new row to your table, MySQL has to write the row (of course), then it also has to write the index entry. So you get an extra write for each added row. It happens quickly, but still you want to be careful: each additional index means an additional write, and it can add up. You're correct that it will take extra disk space, but that wasn't my concern; it was the extra writes.

Comment: @EdGibbs Ah, ofc, it'd currently be around ~2 writes a minute so it's a valid point, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical answer is that option 1 reflects your underlying relationships - a car can be sold to only one country, and therefore a "many to many" relationship (which option 2 suggests) is not appropriate. It would confuse future developers, and pollutes the data model.

The pragmatic answer is that option 2 doesn't appear to have a dramatic performance improvement today, and - crucially - it's likely to introduce complexity into your code. If 99% of the queries don't need the country data, you either have to write the query to include it (thus negating the performance benefit), or build nasty "if I need country THEN query = xxx ELSE query = yyy" logic.

Finally, apropos the indexing question - MySQL only uses one index for a query, so unless you're writing a query where "country" is in the where clause or being joined on, it's unlikely to have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bwoebi, Raphaël Althaus, AgRizzo, Alfons and Ed Gibbs for the input to the question!

Short summary:

- Since there can't be two countries to a car and there's only one extra field needed:

  - Go with **Solution 1**
- Also, an index is probably not needed, check our cardinality and performance on the specific scenario

/Thomas